# Triggering change event

Tags: jquery

I've got the following function:

```
$('#id_service').on('change', function() {

     afunction($(this));
            
});
```

I've then got another function that manually changes #id_service

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#id_primary option:nth-child(2)').attr('selected', 'selected');
       
});
```

This function that sets the section option to select isn't triggering 'on change' function. How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try using the jquery.trigger() function?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#id_primary option:nth-child(2)').attr('selected', 'selected');
       $('#id_service').trigger('change');
    });
```